# Are Session based Singleton Implementations plausible replacements for multiple Session Variables?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I have been considering a Singleton pattern design for a web application to replace the use of Session variables for reasons I'd rather not go into specific detail about; but after researching the topic it seems as though this pattern is probably not the most efficient or effective approach.

So I am now considering an approach that would effectively reap some of the benefits of the Singleton design in combination with the use of Session variables.

The question is as stated, "Are Session based Singleton Implementations plausible replacements for multiple Session Variables"

Hopefully this question is not taken a matter of opinion but rather a matter of fact based on the concepts of Session variables and Singleton pattern designs.

My implementation would look similar to the following:

```
public class SingletonSessionData
{
   // User Identity Properties
   public string UserId { get; set; }
   public string UserName { get; set; }

   private const string SessionData= "UserSessionObject";
   private SingletonSessionData() { }

   public static SingletonSessionData Instance()
   {
       SingletonSessionData oSingleton;
       if(null == System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionData])
       {
           // use private constructor to create an instance, place it into the session
           oSingleton = new SingletonSessionData();
           System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionData] = oSingleton;
       }
       else
       {
           //Retrieve the existing instance 
           oSingleton = (ReportSessionData)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionData];
       }
       return oSingleton;
   }
   // Edited after the initial post to illustrate my proposed method of disposing the object to release memory resources as opposed to dependency of session timeout
   public static void Dispose()
   {
       System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove(SessionData);
   }
}
```

What I am expecting to gain from this approach is to still maintain the persistence of session variables to a specific session but have the benefit of use with Intellisense and what I believe would potentially be more efficient and effective memory management by having the Singleton exist in the session.

Reasonable or no?

Comment: I don't think you gain anything in this structure, because ultimately the session is still at the HttpContext level; this is just a wrapper around it with a reference to itself. And nothing prevents any other page from accessing the Session conventionally. I agree there's nothing inherently *wrong* with it, but I don't know that it's *beneficial*.

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, though I'd call the static property `Current` rather than `Instance` to emphasize that it's related to the current request.  I would also check for `HttpContext.Current` being null, and throw an appropriate exception - this in case some code that isn't related to a request attempts to use your class.  I'd also remove the `Singleton` prefix, because it isn't really a Singleton, is it?

Comment: This looks like the *Session Request Context* lifestyle described on page 265 in [my book](http://amzn.to/12p90MG). As described there, it's likely to degrade your system’s capacity, because sessions never explicitly end, but only time out (by default after 20 minutes). This means that you're going to have objects on your servers that relate to users who left up to 20 minutes ago. Depending on the traffic patterns on your site, this would adversely affect the capacity of the system, so it could be expensive.

Comment: @MarkSeemann, your book looks interesting. I may just buy a copy. With regard to the potential degradation you mentioned, I'd imagine I could do an explicit method to dispose of the object which would ensure the Session termination; could I not or would you consider that a non practical approach?

Comment: @Joe your points are noted. I don't really understand the implication of not being Singleton though. I did not make the class sealed in my example but the concept is based on Singleton pattern. Could you elaborate more on that comment. Out of curiosity. Thanks

Comment: @Mark When and where would you call that disposal method?

Comment: @Mark - Singleton means there's a single instance - whereas in your case there are instances per Session.

Comment: @MarkSeemann I'd most likely call the method upon the user logging off from the site but given the worse case scenario, then I'd expect the normal behavior of the Session which would be to sustain the state until its expired as you previously mentioned. But disregarding my proposed implementation, I would still have objects on the server that could potentially relate to users who left up to 20 minutes ago if I didn't use this implemenation anyway...correct?

Comment: @Joe understood, you're correct in that regard. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: If users explicitly log out, you can attempt to clean up after them. Most web developers experience that this isn't typical user behaviour, but it may be different in your case... Still, even if users explicitly log out, what if you're running on a server farm? Would you then need sticky session?

Comment: In any case, it's unclear what you hope to gain from this approach. Which problem are you trying to solve?